# Launching google maps from another application - How do I set a value for the `destination`?

Tags: android, google-maps

This is my current code, I am launching google maps (**browser version**):

```
        mGoogleMapsAppButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Float sourceLatitude =65.9667f;
            Float sourceLongitude = -18.5333f;
            Float destinationLatitude = 60.4443f;
            Float destinationLongitude = -18.4444f;
            try {
                String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",
                        sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried launching google maps through the **app version**, but I am unsure on how to set the lat/long for the destination, so I came up with this unfinished code:

```
    String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Can't seem to find anything on the docs, I must be blind; any ideas on how to do it?

Bonus question, this code does not work if launched in Genymotion (emulator) as it will throw an **ActivityNotFoundException**, any fix suggestions to this would be appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps might help. Do you want to launch maps in the browser or with the user's default maps app?

Comment: Genymotion is probably missing a default maps app because it doesn't have GooglePlay installed by default. Here are some instructions for that: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support Or you can just use the default emulator in Android Studio w/o Genymotion, making sure that Google Play Services is installed

Comment: I want to launch it in the user's default maps; I checked the documentation above earlier actually, I can't seem to find anything regarding "destination". Mind helping me find more about it?

Comment: @Lyla Thansk for the genymotion link, got google-maps to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using URI String with this. (Setting destination)

```
http://maps.google.com/?daddr=28.5783992,77.3124742
```

Answer (score 0):

This working for me

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+sourceLatitude +","+sourceLongitude
                            +"&daddr="+destinationLatitude+","+destinationLongitude));
            intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```